# Show that if A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a}}$ $\forall x_i \phi$ then A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a}}$ $\phi$.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

The setting for this problem is as follows:

Suppose that A $= \langle A,... \rangle$ is a structure for a language L and that the sequence $\vec{a}$ of elements of A interprets the variables $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$. Let $\phi$ be a formula of L in which $x_i$ does not appear as a free variable. Show that

if A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a}}$ $\forall x_i \phi$ then A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a}}$ $\phi$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106610/discussion-on-question-by-diae-mizou-show-that-if-a-models-vecx-veca).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show that if A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a}}$ $\forall x_i \phi$ then A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a}}$ $\phi$,

Recall that A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a}}$ $\forall x_i \phi$ if and only if for all $b \in A$, A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a} [x_i / b]}$ $\phi$.

Thus by taking $b = a_i$ (where $a_i$ is the element of the sequence $\vec{a}$ which corresponds to $x_i$)

we have that A $\models_{\vec{x} / \vec{a}}$ $\phi$.